# How to set different labelstyles for controls in manipulate?

Tags: manipulate

Background:

```
 Manipulate[
  {jj, kk},
  {{jj, 2, "Select j"}, 1, 11},
  {{kk, 2, "Select k"}, 1, 11},
  LabelStyle -> {Bold, Medium}
 ]
```

In the example above the fonts of the labels "Select j" and "Select k" are, as expected, set to bold and medium size.

**Question: Is there a way to set the labelstyle for each variable individually?**

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `Style` for the labels:

```
Manipulate[{jj, kk},
 {{jj, 2, Style["Select j", Bold, Larger]}, 1, 11},
 {{kk, 2, "Select k"}, 1, 11}]
```